# Changing layout contolls properties without working in xml and just with java

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Im working on a project that uses listmenu for some activities. my java code runs generates this activity and i made no xml file for it. i changed the whole theme but this activity manu still is like first time. if i dont want work with xml for it is there any possibility to change it with java? here is my code for this layout:

```
    package com.bestdiet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;

public class MyMenu extends ListActivity {
    String classes[]={"وضعیت سلامتی","نمونه حرکات ورزشی","اندازه گیری مسافت","تایمر","دیگر بخش ها","ارتباط با ما"};
       String classes2[]={"Healthstate","SampleMovement","DistanceCount","MyTimer","Other","ConnectionWus"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_menu);



        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyMenu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v,int position,long id)
    {



        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese=classes2[position];


    try{
    Class myclass= Class.forName("com.bestdiet." + cheese);
    Intent i=new Intent(MyMenu.this,myclass);
    startActivity(i);

    }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont see any layout code

Comment: yes there is no layout. i just added code for my list menu. i just want the background be black.how can i do it without working xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"i just want the background be black.how can i do it without working xml layout?"

In the `onCreate()` method of your activity do

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i align my menu item texts to right or center in java?

Comment: Use the `android:gravity` property

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=android+align+view+programmatically&oq=android+align+view&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4610j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8